# How to secure read with the Bash "read" command?

Tags: bash

You know there is a built-in Bash command called `read`. What if I want to do this in my scripts:

```
read PASSWROD
```

When it prompts me to input, all my input is visible.
Is there an alternative command that can make the input invisible.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Time to learn how to manual bash (in the [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) manual, that is; this is from the Bash 4.1 edition).  The relevant option is `-s`.

> #### [read](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read)
>
> `read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt]`
>
> `[-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]`
>
> One line is read from the standard input, or from the file descriptor fd supplied
>   as an argument to the `-u` option, and the first word is assigned to the first
>   name, the second word to the second name, and so on, with leftover words and
>   their intervening separators assigned to the last name. If there are fewer words
>   read from the input stream than names, the remaining names are assigned
>   empty values. The characters in the value of the IFS variable are used to split
>   the line into words. The backslash character `\` may be used to remove any
>   special meaning for the next character read and for line continuation. If no
>   names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable REPLY. The return
>   code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out (in which case the return code is greater than 128), or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the argument to `-u`.
>
> Options, if supplied, have the following meanings:
>
> `-a aname` The words are assigned to sequential indices of the array variable
>   aname, starting at 0. All elements are removed from aname before
>   the assignment. Other name arguments are ignored.
>
> `-d delim` The first character of delim is used to terminate the input line,
>   rather than newline.
>
> `-e` Readline (see Chapter 8 [Command Line Editing], page 93) is used
>   to obtain the line. Readline uses the current (or default, if line
>   editing was not previously active) editing settings.
>
> `-i text` If Readline is being used to read the line, text is placed into the
>   editing buffer before editing begins.
>
> `-n nchars` read returns after reading nchars characters rather than waiting
>   for a complete line of input, but honor a delimiter if fewer than
>   nchars characters are read before the delimiter.
>
> `-N nchars` read returns after reading exactly nchars characters rather than
>   waiting for a complete line of input, unless EOF is encountered or
>   read times out. Delimiter characters encountered in the input are
>   not treated specially and do not cause read to return until nchars
>   characters are read.
>
> `-p prompt` Display prompt, without a trailing newline, before attempting to
>   read any input. The prompt is displayed only if input is coming
>   from a terminal.
>
> `-r` If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character.
>   The backslash is considered to be part of the line. In particular, a
>   backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line continuation.
>
> `-s` Silent mode. If input is coming from a terminal, characters are not
>   echoed.
>
> `-t timeout`
>   Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of input
>   is not read within timeout seconds. timeout may be a decimal
>   number with a fractional portion following the decimal point. This
>   option is only effective if read is reading input from a terminal,
>   pipe, or other special file; it has no effect when reading from regular
>   files. If timeout is 0, read returns success if input is available on
>   the specified file descriptor, failure otherwise. The exit status is
>   greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded.
>
> `-u fd` Read input from file descriptor fd.

---

Hence, with the typo fixed, you need:

```
read -s -p "Password: " PASSWORD
```

You may want to add an `echo` immediately after it since the newline isn't echoed either (though it is not included in the password).

Answer (score 10):

You can use these few lines:

```
stty -echo
read -p "Password: " passw; echo
stty echo
```

This will turn `echo` on and off between password reading.

Answer (score 2):

You can use terminal settings to turn echo off:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Disable echo
stty -echo

#Prompt and read password
printf "Password: "
read PASSWORD

# Turn echo back on
stty echo
printf "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
read -s -p "Password: " passw
```

works on bash