# My bash script verification code does not work

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

I am trying to write a program where the user can enter a username and password, then the code should check if the username and password are correct unfortunately whenever it checks no matter if the username/password is correct of not it will echo "Username Verified".

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Username"  
read username  
echo "Password"
read password
sleep 1
correct_u=user
correct_p=pass
if [[ $username -eq $correct_u ]]
then
  echo "Username Verified..."
else 
  echo "Username Incorect..."
fi
sleep 1
if [[ $correct_p -eq $password ]]
then 
  sleep 1
  echo "Password Verified..."
else 
  echo "Password Incorect..."
fi
```

I have tired checking that all the variables work

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Use [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for asking good questions that get good, quick answers.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `username` and `correct_u` consist solely of digits, `[[ $username -eq $correct_u ]]` will always evaluate to *true*, since `-eq` forces the arguments to be numbers, and if there are no number, the arguments are treated as zero.

To do a string comparision, do

```
[[ $username == "$correct_u" ]]
```

Quoting the right-hand side is important here, to avoid that it is interpreted as glob-pattern, since `==` in general does a wildcard match.

Comment: The single `=` does the same, the magic is from `[[ ]]` afaik.

Comment: @Jetchisel: Yes; according to the man page: _The = operator is equivalent to ==. _  It's a matter of taste. I usually prefer the `==` form, perhaps this is the way many programming languages express equality. But the point of my answer is that you can't use `-eq` here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `=` instead of `-eq` when comparing strings in bash. `=` is used for string comparison while `-eq` is used for integer comparison:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Username"  
read username  
echo "Password"
read password
sleep 1
correct_u=user
correct_p=pass
if [[ "$username" = "$correct_u" ]]
then
  echo "Username Verified..."
else 
  echo "Username Incorrect..."
fi
sleep 1
if [[ "$correct_p" = "$password" ]]
then 
  sleep 1
  echo "Password Verified..."
else 
  echo "Password Incorrect..."
fi
```

Comment: if you consider this answer is useful please mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Embedding your name & pw in cleartext in the file isn't ideal. The user ID must be able to read it to execute the commands in it; executable permissions won't help if you take away read.

Use that to your advantage. Set the user/group/world permissions appropriately. Then the user and password are entered at login...

You might want to combine methods from [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/734838/how-to-use-encrypted-passwords-in-bash-scripts/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202187/8656552), reading the right password securely from a vault file and comparing that to the one you read *silently* from the user.

But first, as already mentioned - fix your test.

```
$: [[ "one" -eq "two" ]] && echo same || echo no
same

$: [[ "one" == "two" ]] && echo same || echo no
no

$: [[ "one" == "one" ]] && echo same || echo no
same
```